# Align error text in center from validator in flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to put the error message in the middle.

How can I put the error text in the center of the validator's textformfiled?

what do you suggest?

```
Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: borderRadius,
                  ),
                  width: screenWidth,
                  constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 400),
                  height: containerSizeEmail,
                  child: TextFormField(
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                    controller: emailController,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      alignLabelWithHint: true,
                      fillColor: Colors.white,
                      filled: true,
                      errorStyle: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 10.0,
                       
                      ),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: borderRadius,
                      ),
                      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 35.0),
                      labelText: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.enterEmail,
                      prefixIcon: const Padding(
                        padding:  EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 15.0),
                        child: Icon(Icons.email,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    validator: (value) {
                      String textToReturn = "";
                      setState(() {
                        if (value!.isEmpty) {
                          containerSizeEmail = containerSizeLarge;
                          textToReturn =
                              AppLocalizations.of(context)!.enterEmail;
                        } else if (!EmailValidator.validate(value, true)) {
                          containerSizeEmail = containerSizeLarge;
                          textToReturn =
                              AppLocalizations.of(context)!.enterValidEmail;                                                             
                        } else {
                          containerSizeEmail = containerSizeNormal;
                        }
                      });
                      return textToReturn == "" ? null : textToReturn;
                    },
                  ),
                ),
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpCsO.png

solutions to solve please

Answer (score 0):

You cannot align the error text. You can try adding a text widget and return null from validator and show error msg only if the textToReturn is not empty like the following

```
Column(
 children: [
   Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: borderRadius,
                  ),
                  width: screenWidth,
                  constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 400),
                  height: containerSizeEmail,
                  child: TextFormField(
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                    controller: emailController,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      alignLabelWithHint: true,
                      fillColor: Colors.white,
                      filled: true,
                      errorStyle: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 10.0,
                       
                      ),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: borderRadius,
                      ),
                      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 35.0),
                      labelText: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.enterEmail,
                      prefixIcon: const Padding(
                        padding:  EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 15.0),
                        child: Icon(Icons.email,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    validator: (value) {
                      String textToReturn = "";
                      setState(() {
                        if (value!.isEmpty) {
                          containerSizeEmail = containerSizeLarge;
                          textToReturn =
                              AppLocalizations.of(context)!.enterEmail;
                        } else if (!EmailValidator.validate(value, true)) {
                          containerSizeEmail = containerSizeLarge;
                          textToReturn =
                              AppLocalizations.of(context)!.enterValidEmail;                                                             
                        } else {
                          containerSizeEmail = containerSizeNormal;
                        }
                      });
                      return null;
                    },
                  ),
                ),
  if(textToReturn != "")
   Text(textToReturn, style: TextStyle(
     fontSize: 10,
     color : Colors.red
    ))
     
   )

 ]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

To be honest i don't know any thing that can do that, but i start thinking of classic solution of an old school:

you want to display the error text in the center of the screen, **give it a prefix space equal to the the half of screen width.**

Try:

```
  validator: (s){
    String returnedString = '';

    if(s!.isEmpty)
      {
        for(int i =0 ; i < MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/8 ; i++ ){
          returnedString += '\t';
        }
        returnedString+= 'Error!!';
        return returnedString;
      }
    return null;
  }
```

There's a correlation between `1/8 of screen width` and `/t` it's a long story, **related to pixels.**

At last i don't claim it's the optimal solution, but stills out of Box.

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

You can try error argument it accepts a widget so you can play with it

```
String errorText = "";
return Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: borderRadius,
  ),
  width: screenWidth,
  constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 400),
  height: containerSizeEmail,
  child: TextFormField(
    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
    controller: emailController,
    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      alignLabelWithHint: true,
      fillColor: Colors.white,
      filled: true,
      error: Visibility(
        visible: errorText.isNotEmpty,
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Text(
            errorText,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      errorStyle: const TextStyle(
        fontSize: 10.0,
      ),
      border: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: borderRadius,
      ),
      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 35.0),
      labelText: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.enterEmail,
      prefixIcon: const Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 15.0),
        child: Icon(
          Icons.email,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    validator: (value) {
      String textToReturn = "";
      setState(() {
        if (value!.isEmpty) {
          containerSizeEmail = containerSizeLarge;
          textToReturn = AppLocalizations.of(context)!.enterEmail;
        } else if (!EmailValidator.validate(value, true)) {
          containerSizeEmail = containerSizeLarge;
          textToReturn = AppLocalizations.of(context)!.enterValidEmail;
        } else {
          containerSizeEmail = containerSizeNormal;
        }
        errorText = textToReturn;
      });
      return textToReturn == "" ? null : textToReturn;
    },
  ),
);
```